# phpunit not working on a fresh installation of laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I'm having a problem with my freshly installed Laravel.

when I'm trying to use `phpunit` command to run default `ExampleTest.php` , I got this **error** :

```
D:\Laravel\Rahimi0151>phpunit
PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 277
PHP Warning:  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 285

Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php on line 285
PHPUnit 3.7.21 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from D:\Laravel\Rahimi0151\phpunit.xml



Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.00Mb

[30;43m[2KNo tests executed!
[0m[2K
```

and at the bottom, it says :

> `No tests executed!`

Can someone please help me with a solution?

Comment: how about `phpunit "path/to/ExampleTest.extension"`? How should phpunit know what test to execute?

Comment: That does not look good: the given version of PHPUnit is more than four years old. And what have you configured such that the given test file is executed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem here is that you are running PHPUnit installed on your system that is pretty old and not PHPUnit that should be run for this project.

To make sure you run the PHPUnit that is really installed for this project you should rather run:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit
```

or

```
vendor/bin/phpunit.bat
```

Answer (score -1):

In case somebody is searching for the answer here it is:

`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`

and make sure that your function contains the word "test"

for example

```php
public function test_a_user_can_browse_threads()
{
...
}
```

edit: this works for laravel version 7

Comment: In laravel 7 you really don't need that,just run:   php artisan test

Answer (score -1):

Running Lumen version 7.0, and was instructed to simply run `phpunit`

However running `phpunit` always produced `No Test Executed` error.

Tried Admir Husić's advice, ran `php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit`, and problem solved, Lumen found the test file and executed it.

Thanks.